# Angular Form is Not Returning Error if I am return Error with async and await. With AngularFire2

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

This code is working fine

```
async save(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  const file = input.files.item(0);

  if (this.form.valid) {
    const data = this.form.getRawValue();
    await this.fireDatabase.object(`/Devices/${data.name}`).set(data);
    this.snackBar.open('Device successfully created', 'close', {
      duration: 2000
    });
    this.form.reset();
    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

But If I checking with `if` condition

```
async save(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  const file = input.files.item(0);

  if (this.form.valid) {
    if (true) {
      this.snackBar.open('error', 'close', {
        duration: 2000
      });
    }
    const data = this.form.getRawValue();

    await this.fireDatabase.object(`/Devices/${data.name}`).set(data);

    this.snackBar.open('Device successfully created', 'close', {
      duration: 2000
    });
    this.form.reset();
    input.value = '';
  }
}
```

then it doesn't return function.

How do I fix this?

I'm using Angular and Angularfire

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a `Promise` from there as well using `return Promise.resolve();`

```
async save(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  const file = input.files.item(0);

  if (this.form.valid) {
    if (true) {
      this.snackBar.open('error', 'close', {
        duration: 2000
      });
    }
    const data = this.form.getRawValue();

    await this.fireDatabase.object(`/Devices/${data.name}`).set(data);

    this.snackBar.open('Device successfully created', 'close', {
      duration: 2000
    });
    this.form.reset();
    input.value = '';
  }
  else {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

}
```